# How big would a artificial island have to be to bring about massive economic and ecologic repercussions for the rest of the globe

Tags: science-based

If someone were to create an artificial island by digging into the mantle and using nuclear bombs to cause islands to form, then how big could an island have to be for the world to be in danger or for there to be serious repercussions, etc?

Comment: Tags please. Do not use this tag alone, says the science based tag description.

Comment: It doesn't matter to the world economy how big it is if there's no magically appearing instant population to go with it, you either worded that wrong for what you mean or I think you need to check your thinking on this :)

Comment: Highly depends on the location. Try doing this on top of a big oilfield in the bay of Mexico and you will have massive economic and ecologic repercussions.

Comment: Not sure the point you are going for, and dubious of the method of producing an island with nukes. that aside if you are looking for a bad place to put an island. I can think of fewer places that would jack up the planet for the most people than the drake passage between the southern tip of S America and Antarctica. [link]https://www.researchgate.net/publication/253911956_Did_the_opening_of_the_Drake_Passage_play_a_significant_role_in_Cenozoic_cooling

Answer (score 3):

/ digging into the mantle and using nuclear bombs to cause islands to form/

**Flaunting this kind of tech will by itself cause serious repercussions!**

Even gentle little nuclear tests are these days considered gauche by the world movers and shakers.  Deploying nuclear bombs, disrupting the mantle and producing real moving and shaking would get everyone's attention, right then.   This regardless of the outcome of the endeavor. It is the equivalent of one of the renters enlarging his basement apartment using a backhoe and fire.  We all live upstairs!

An entity who not only had this kind of power but was willing to use it in some sort of halfassed endeavor like this is dangerous both because of the forces involved but also the colossal lack of judgement this shows.  This entity needs a time out and dangerous toys confiscated.

But maybe it would be a good thing.  If there were ever an event that could get squabbling world powers to agree and work together it would be something like this.

Comment: "If there were ever an event that could get squabbling world powers to think, 'hey, there's free nukes! I'd better get to them before anybody else!'" FTFY

Answer (score 2):

**People would be less concerned with the island and more with the earthquakes and nuclear fallout.**

The method you're describing to raise this island sounds dangerous at best and potentially world-ending at the worst. There's a reason why people were so afraid of nuclear warheads going off during the Cold War. The effect of even one bomb going off can reach untold distances and kill countless people and animals both directly and indirectly. You're proposing multiple being ignited in an attempt to form an entire chain of islands.

Even if they were dropped between a layer of molten rock, the sheer force of even one explosion would be deadly in itself. Nuclear bombs generally have their powers measured in kilotons, as in the amount of power 1000 tons of TNT would produce. And that's just a low-balled estimate. Most nukes are significantly more powerful than this.

Also, in no sane world would you construct an island using a nuke. That's like using a missile to hammer in a nail, or using a block of dynamite to perform surgery.

When people think about nuclear bombs, they generally only think about the danger of the explosion itself. But that's not even half the battle. Radiation can contaminate an area for years, and it can cause horrifying burns, illnesses, and birth defects. If the heat of the explosion was the only thing that killed, they would not be half the weapons they are.

My point is, any island you would produce with such deadly weapons would most likely be rendered completely inhabitable.

The layer of rock between the bombs and the mantle might be able to offer enough protection from the fallout, but I somehow doubt that it would.

If the radiation couldn't kill anyone from that far below the earth, then I guess you would be safe, but you'd still have to run against the consequences of messing with the Earth's tectonics in a drastic way.

For example, once you've blown a hole in the Earth, how do you know you haven't weakened the integrity of it to the point that it's just going to collapse back in on itself. Imagine trying to make an island only to have it collapse in on itself as a massive sinkhole.

Now let's say everything succeeded and somehow none of these things managed to kill a large portion of the population. Messing with the tectonic plates somehow didn't cause disastrous earthquakes, and the nuclear radiation did not manage to make everyone in a 1000 kilometer radius serious burns and cancers.

You are now left with a new island. How big does it have to be to cause serious repercussions? It doesn't have to be, you've just created a new island presumably in the middle of the ocean. Every news organization in the world is going to be fascinated, every scientist in the world is probably going to wonder how it was made, and every world government is probably going to want it for themselves if it's worth anything.

Some governments might declare it an act of war to make something like this so close to their homeland and their native waters. Imagine how the US would react if a new island the size of Cuba appeared out of nowhere in their waters. They'd probably want it to be there's, no matter how small it was.

If the island in question is the size of Australia, then we have a real problem. Ocean trade routes would be massively affected. Sailors would have to navigate around the place. Currents and tides would probably be dramatically changed as well, leading to massive changes in climate. Sea creatures that used to live where the island was are now all dead. You've probably irreparably ruined the ecosystem of the ocean. Large groups of fishermen are now out of the job and large groups of people starve. Great job.

If the island is the size of a continent, you've officially doomed the world. Any part of the ocean floor that you raised is now dead. Currents and tides are thrown out of whack. What used to be an ocean is now a desert. The rest of the ocean has to go somewhere, so you'll probably have global floods everywhere but your island. People will be forced to either move there or run for the high ground. Climate is thrown out of balance and weather is chaotic. Tidal waves wipe out major cities, killing untold millions.

I think you get my point.

There's not a single way I can imagine this going well.

Islands are usually formed over thousands of years through careful natural processes. Even if you try to make an artificial island safely, you'd have to accept that you're going to throw off the delicate balance of nature.

If you try to make an island by recklessly putting a thousand nukes under the ocean, then you're civilization is just asking to be annihilated.

Comment: Ummm okay, I'm not really interested in the lives of others I was asking if you would have a nuclear winter-esque type event

Comment: I have already addressed this in my answer.

Comment: Set off bombs under the mantle, you'd still get nuclear fallout. The only way to prevent that is by burying the bombs deep under the ground. Also, as I mentioned in my answer, if you raise a massive island out of the ground, you'll cause mass flooding, disrupt tide flows, and ruin the climate. So to answer your question, yes. You 'll either have a nuclear winter or something close to a nuclear winter.

Comment: "The effect of even one bomb going off can reach untold distances and kill countless people and animals both directly and indirectly." Truth be told, just a nuke going into the upper atmosphere isn't going to kill more than those inside the blast radius, as long as the fireball doesn't touch the ground. The real problem starts when the nuke raise irradiated soil and becomes a dirty bomb - which definitely is the case of creating an artificial island by boring the crust to the mantle using nuke**s**...

Comment: ... You need heaps of more nukes to do it though. The [largest nuke detonated by humans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsar_Bomba#Test_results) was a mere 58Mt (could have reached double that). The [Chicxulub impactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicxulub_crater#Impact_specifics) delivered 100 million times that much, caused the Cretaceous–Paleogene extinction event, and yet it did **not** bored the crust enough to form an island.

Answer (score 0):

It has already been mentioned that just doing so would be a problem because of the use of nuclear weapons. I am going to focus on another problem, Archimedes principle basically says that any body in a liquid displaces an equivalent volume of the body, that is your island is 100km³ means that you will displace 100km³ of water and 100km³ is a ridiculously small volume for an island, yours would be much larger if you want to be able to have luxury cities or whatever you want to put. Basically your island would cause the sea level to rise, how bad is that? Depends on how much it would cause the sea level to rise. 1cm probably wouldn't be that bad but it would be noticeable, 5cm would flood several cities, 10cm would directly cause some countries to disappear, 1m would cause the apocalypse.
As if this were not enough, ocean currents would be altered. Currents are caused by differences in salt concentrations, viscosity, temperature, among others. Your island would alter the currents in every possible way. And how bad is that? Much, much more than you imagine.You would literally change the climate of the planet and mess with the water cycle. Plus using so many nuclear weapons would put your country on a par with North Korea in the eyes of the international community.